# What is the proper way to create a custom user field programatically?

Tags: entities, installation

I'm currently working a custom user registration module for a project I'm busy with. I need to add a boolean field which will be attached to user entities. The value will just serve as a flag to check whether a user has answered a CAPTCHA question as a final step of registration. I've been trying to define a boolean field which should have no widget selection dropdown or edit / delete operations within the "Manage fields" section for users.

It seems that the best way to define the field would be during hook_enable or hook_field_schema (inside your .install file), but I'm confused as to what the best practise is.

Also, is there anyway to give the database table a better name when defining your field? I find the table prefix for fields "field_data_xx" pretty confusing if you're defining numerous custom fields.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: The field should be added in `hook_enable()` and removed in `hook_disable()` if you want the field to be removed and then added when you enable/disable the module. However I suggest implementing it in `hook_install()` and `hook_uninstall` as that will only remove the field and its data from the user entity when the module is uninstalled as oppose to simply disabled. `hook_field_schema` is not for these kinds of tasks as it's for defining a database table.

Q2: You'd have to hack your way through the field.module to make these database table name changes. This is really bad practice (VERY VERY) and plus I don't see the point of this, or never even heard anyone attempting this. The database tables are for Drupal and not for human eyes. As such they're in a consistent and systematic naming conventions so the field module as well as other modules that use them can easily extract data.

Comment: thanks for your response. Makes sense regarding the database table names, guess I was just being fussy :)